# how to pass json dictionary as parameter afnetworking post

Tags: json, dictionary, afnetworking

I have searched many links to post json dictionary as parameter in afnetworking. I have converted dictionary to json format string, unfortunately afnetworking post allows nsdictionary values as parameter. In server side json format dictionary is only accepted.My code follows, please suggest me any method in afnetworking.Thanks

```
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", nil];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"email":txt_email.text,@"password":txt_password.text,@"platform":@"iphone"};

    NSString *str_url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@do_signup",BaseURLlogin];

   [manager POST:str_url parameters: params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
```